# Using WildCard for dateTime column in SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to look for all records within a table that has date column for a specific date, at the moment I am trying this query,

```
SELECT     *
FROM      Table_ABC
WHERE     DateCreated CONTAINS 24/10/2012
```

But its not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the DateCreated column is a DATETIME type, you should try:

```
SELECT     *
FROM      Table_ABC
WHERE     YEAR(DateCreated) = 2012
AND       MONTH(DateCreated) = 10
AND       DAY(DateCreated) = 24
```

or simply

```
SELECT     *
FROM      Table_ABC
WHERE     DATE(DateCreated) = "2012-10-24"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Select * from Table_ABC where DateCreated between '24/10/2012 HH:MM:SS' and '24/10/2012 HH:MM:SS'
```

Changes hours minutes and seconds to be what you want it to be and it's usually in 24 hour time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following statement:

```sql
SELECT    *
FROM      Table_ABC
WHERE     CONVERT(DATE, DateCreated) = '2012-10-24'
```

Reference for CONVERT:
https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql